# AS3 OOP MVC with PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3, model-view-controller, oop, actionscript

I'm new to ActionScript and Flex 3... I'm trying to develop an MVC 100% OOP application with Flex 3 using MXML, AS3 and PHP.

- M (PHP)
- V (MXML)
- C (AS3)

The 3 layers I choose for my development. I have 10 AS3 classes that are object related between them and some inherit or implement interfaces.

The only problem here is how to interact 100% OOP with my model. In this case my model has to be a PHP Class that needs to be called from AS3 (the controller).

For example the AS3 class : Patient have a method called Save:

```
    public function Save(data:Array) : void
    {
        /* PHP call - model layer */
    }
```

I want to create an instance of my PHP Patient Model class that connects to the DB and insert the data array into it.

What should I use? How can I also return a variable to AS3? What happen to AS3 if there is a cached Exception in PHP?

Comment: check out http://www.amfphp.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you got it a bit wrong as where PHP fits into the mix. (Or I got you wrong)
1. MVC is flex usage only
Model - inside flex (as3)
View - Flex view
Controller - Flex controller

PHP fits into the mix when using MVCS
s--> Service.

Now, as for the MVC part, you can use frameworks like Mate (by Afusion) or the RobotLegs.
Both are great, I love Mate and have been using it for quite a while now, the advantage of Mate is you use only Puse Flex/AS3 object an none framework-specific objects.

After connecting to your service from the controller, or from the MAP (if you are using Mate) you can receive/send data using AMF --> ActionScript Messaging Format.

But still, you have to hold a client side class representation for every server side one.
for example --> User.php --> User.as --> ArrayCollection of User and so on and so forth.

Comment: I agree with everything @KensoDev said, except I think Swiz (http://swizframework.org/) is superior to the aforementioned microframeworks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Haxe](http://old.haxe.org/doc/intro). Simply use it instead of AS3 and PHP. Use Haxe serialization to transport objects between application tiers. You may even want to use [Haxe remoting](http://old.haxe.org/doc/remoting) to make things simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You should to use [flash remoting](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash_remoting/) with ZendAMF or amfPHP It will make remote PHP methods accessible from flash